# Ionic AngularJS splitting up events by date

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm currently pulling events from `Google Calendar` and displaying them into the screen, this is the html :

```
<div class="list card" data-ng-repeat="x in items">

 <div class="item item-avatar">
    <img src="image.jpg">
    <h2>{{x.summary}}</h2>
    <p>{{x.ncreated}}</p>
  </div>

  <div class="item item-body">

    <p>
     {{x.description}}
    </p>
    <p>
</div>
```

`ncreated` is the date and time of the appointment. What I want to do is add some html for each day so when the date match today I want a spacer with some text saying `TODAY APPOINTMENTS` and then the same for `TOMMOROW` then `NEXT WEEK` then `MONTH` .

I'm finding it hard to figure out how to push this html depending on the date, where do you do the logic and how does it effect the html? Not sure if this is relevant but here is the snippet in the controller :

```
for (a=0;a<$scope.items.length;a++){
        //crt=$scope.items[a].created;

        if($scope.items[a].status == "confirmed"){
            console.log($scope.items[a].status);
        crt=$scope.items[a].start.dateTime;
        svals=crt.split("T");
        dvals=svals[0].split("-");
        tvals=svals[1].split(":");
        ncreated=dvals[2]+"/"+dvals[1]+"/"+dvals[0];
        ncreated+=" "+tvals[0]+":"+tvals[1];
        $scope.items[a].ncreated=ncreated;
        }
    }
```

Comment: did you check momentjs.com ? you can check difference between dates with it

Answer (score 0):

You can add a call to function in your controller with date as parameter.
It's something like this:

```
<div class="list card" data-ng-repeat="x in items">

 <div class="item item-avatar">
    <img src="image.jpg">
    <h2>{{x.summary}}</h2>
    <p>{{x.ncreated}}{{addSomeHtml(x.ncreated)}}</p>

  </div>

  <div class="item item-body">

    <p>
     {{x.description}}
    </p>
    <p>
</div>
```

And in your controller add function to $scope:

```
$scope.addSomeHtml = function(date){

}
```

To do the comparaison between dates, simpest way is to use [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/).

Comment: Oh i can dynamically add html by just returning string?

Comment: Yes. That's power of Angular

Comment: The HTML just displays as a string

Comment: I have tried <div ng-bind-html="{{addSomeHtml(x.ncreated)}}"></div>

Comment: You have to use angularjs sanitizer.  Check [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize/service/$sanitize) for example. It's allow return html ant not only simpe strings

Comment: If you can share your code in github. i will check it.

Comment: It wont work outside the network, i have <p>{{addSomeHtml(x.ncreated)}}</p> like you said in the comment and var html = "<p>your appointment is at <strong>" + date + "</strong></p>";
  return $compile(html); in the function in the controller and this is the controller function .controller('GoogleCtrl', function($scope,$state,$filter,$compile,$window,AppServer,AppHelper,AppStorage,$cordovaInAppBrowser) {

Comment: I create you a very simple example here: https://plnkr.co/edit/6F5JMLSflolyGtOIc7gs?p=preview

Comment: it's use $sce and not sanitizer